# Is the appreciation in bitcoins taxable?

Tags: taxes

If you have large gains in bitcoin, is there any way that it can be taxed?  If I have $5000, and it appreciates to $10,000 worth of bitcoin, when I sell bitcoin for dollars can it be taxed as a capital gain?  I would think that since there is no documentation to support it that it would be difficult.

Comment: Please specify a country if you're asking about taxes.

Comment: I'm giving this a +1, but I also flagged the question as belonging on Personal Finance.SO. However, please slightly-modify your question so that it is more generic to the value of digital assets and other e-currencies, rather than just Bitcoin.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that as long as you have a receipt for the buy, and one for the sell then there is no reason why the government would say no to taking their share if it. I guess it's just classed as currency trading??